# Rust Tuple destructuring with references

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Take the following code

```
let t : &&mut (&str, u8) =  &&mut ("hallo", 1u8);
let (n, a) = t;
```

`t` could for example be the input in a `.iter_mut().find()` closure.

Rust analyzer and the compiler will assign `n` the type `&&str` and `a` the type `&u8`

My question is why. Where is one level of indirection going? I would have expected `n` to have type `&&mut &str`.

Comment: Why `&&mut` in the first place?

Comment: Rust does not *destruct* the tuple. The tuple remains alive, and `t` still owns the data (a `str` pointer and `u8`). Therefore you get only references in `n` and `a`. If you want to destruct the tuple, it needs to go out of scope or you'd have to Drop it manually.

Comment: This behaviour is called "match ergonomics", and we get questions about it almost daily. It's explained in detail in the [match ergonomics RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html). My personal recommendation is to never use match ergonomics, and instead stick with `ref` and `ref mut` as we did before, because that's a lot less confusing.

Comment: @tadman As I wrote you would get this type in `iter_mut().find(|t|)` for a `Vec<(&str, u8)>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html#binding-mode-rules) is what is coming into play in the pattern match expression "`let (n, a) = t;`". Or, more specifically, "binding mode rules" are being applied.

The compiler makes some assumptions, and simplifies the referencing somewhat on the match. The following code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23442e5fdeb095254fae2ef47886e89e)) goes to some extremes to illustrate the behavior. The output below it shows what the eventual effect on referencing is.

```
fn typestr<T>(_: &T) -> &str { std::any::type_name::<T>() }

macro_rules! print_type {
    ( $($t: expr),* ) => {{ 
        $( print!("{}: {:<12}", stringify!($t), typestr(&$t)); )* println!();
    }}
}

fn main() {
    let t : &mut (&str, u8) = &mut ("hallo", 1u8);// <- t declared with type spec.
    let (n, a) = t;                               // <- destructuring assignment.
    print_type!(n, a, t);
    
    let t : &&mut (&str, u8) = &&mut ("hallo", 1u8);
    let (n, a) = t;
    print_type!(n, a, t);
    
    let t : &&&&mut (&str, u8) = &&&&mut ("hallo", 1u8);
    let (n, a) = t;
    print_type!(n, a, t);
    
    let t : &mut &mut &mut &mut &mut (&str, u8) =  
            &mut &mut &mut &mut &mut ("hallo", 1u8);
    let (n, a) = t;
    print_type!(n, a, t);
}
```

**Output:**

```bash
n: &mut &str   a: &mut u8     t: &mut (&str, u8)
n: &&str       a: &u8         t: &&mut (&str, u8)
n: &&str       a: &u8         t: &mut &&&mut (&str, u8)
n: &mut &str   a: &mut u8     t: &mut &mut &mut &mut &mut (&str, u8)
```

As can be seen, the referencing has been ajusted somewhat for the second and third examples. The final line of output shows how the mutability can be preserved for multiple mutable indirections. The trick is `&mut` needs to be applied to each referencing operator. Otherwise, the mutability is lost.

This diagram from the RFC linked above shows how the automatic referencing adjustments are performed:

```bash
                        Start                                
                          |                                  
                          v                                  
                +-----------------------+                     
                | Default Binding Mode: |                     
                |        move           |                     
                +-----------------------+                     
               /                        \                     
Encountered   /                          \  Encountered       
  &mut val   /                            \     &val
            v                              v                  
+-----------------------+        +-----------------------+    
| Default Binding Mode: |        | Default Binding Mode: |    
|        ref mut        |        |        ref            |    
+-----------------------+        +-----------------------+    
                          ----->                              
                        Encountered                           
                            &val
```

Because in the OP's example, only the second reference is mutable (`&&mut`), and the first is not, the mutability is lost on the destructuring assignment.